# ASP.NET Core: Pulling data to Choices library with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core project, I am pulling data to the second select element according to the ID value of the data I selected in the first select element with Ajax.

Ajax code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#choices-single-brand").change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Inventory/ListModel?id=" + id,
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    var modelSelect = $("#choices-single-model");
                    modelSelect.empty();

                    $.each(data, function (index, model) {
                        modelSelect.append($("<option>", {
                            value: model.modelID,
                            text: model.modelName
                        }));
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr, status, error);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

It is added to the normal select element as <option>, there is no problem here. But I'm also using the choices library, so I can't see the data. I restarted the library in the success function with Ajax, but it doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you talking about :https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices? Could you share some codes related? so taht we could reproduce your issue?